# Reducing system time usage of Python Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, grid-computing

I have a python script that uses multiprocessing's pool.map( ... ) to run a large number of calculations in parallel. Each of these calculations consists of the python script setting up input for a fortran program, using subprocess.popen( ... , stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE ) to run the program, dump the input to it and read the output. Then the script parses the output, gets the needed numbers, then does it again for the next run.

```
def main():
    #Read a configuration file
    #do initial setup
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=maxProc)
    runner = CalcRunner( things that are the same for each run )
    runNumsAndChis = pool.map( runner, xrange(startRunNum, endRunNum))
    #dump the data that makes it past a cut to disk

class CalcRunner(object):
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        #setup member variables
    def __call__(self, runNumber):
        #get parameters for this run
        params = self.getParams(runNum)
        inFileLines = []
        #write the lines of the new input file to a list
        makeInputFile(inFileLines, ... )
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmdString, bufsize=0, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, ... )
        output = proc.communicate( "".join(inFileLines) )
        #get the needed numbers from stdout
        chi2 = getChiSq(output[0])
        return [runNumber, chi2]
    ...
```

Anyways, on to the reason for the question. I submit this script to a grid engine system to break this huge parameter space sweep into 1000, 12 core (I choose 12 since most of the grid is 12 cores), tasks. When a single task runs on a single 12 core machine about 1/3 of the machine's time is spent doing system stuff, and the other 2/3 of the time is doing the user calculations, presumably setting up inputs to ECIS (the aforementioned FORTRAN code), running ECIS, and parsing the output of ECIS. However, sometimes 5 tasks get sent to a 64 core machine to utilize 60 of its cores. On that machine 40% of the time is spent doing system stuff and 1-2% doing user stuff.

First of all, where are all the system calls coming from? I tried writing a version of the program that runs ECIS once per separate thread and keeps piping new input to it and it spends FAR more time in system (and is slower overall), so it doesn't seem like it is due to all the process creation and deletion.
Second of all, how do I go about decreasing the amount of time spent on system calls?

At a guess, the open a process once and keep sending input to it was slower because I had to turn gfortran's output buffering off to get anything from the process, nothing else worked (short of modifying the fortran code... which isn't happening).

The OS on my home test machines where I developed this is Fedora 14. The OS on the grid machines is a recent version of Red Hat.

I have tried playing around with bufsize, setting it to -1 (system defaults), 0 (unbuffered), 1 (line by line), and 64Kb that does not seem to change things.

Comment: If you truly want performance you will have to look at low level languages like C, not python to remove the overheads. As general as it may seem, that is the reality of it.

Comment: You should say which OS you're using, so people can suggest appropriate tools to investigate where the system time is going.

Comment: @Puciek, if the system time is going to I/O (whether files or pipes), C isn't going to help.  After all, CPython's I/O is already done **by** C code ;-)

Comment: @Puciek: My problem is that I seem to be deadlocking the kernel with system calls somehow, not that the script itself is not running fast enough. When it runs single threaded it takes the script 0.013 seconds to setup an input file and parse the output, it takes ECIS (compiled with full optimizations) 0.035 seconds to perform the calculation. In terms of overhead I am fairly happy it's just this system time mess that I am trying to resolve.

Comment: I don't see anything that would point toward IO issues, just calling a process as sub is not going to cause them (unless overdone to some extreme in amount and/or footprint of the sub). And that deadlocking as you call it can be caused by MANY issues, starting with GIL, going through some system issues and ending with just inefficient implementation of the spawning process.

Comment: Aren't I avoiding the Global Interpretter Lock with the pool.map call? I thought that was the whole POINT of the multiprocessing module?

Comment: @JamesMatta, yes, multiprocessing creates truly distinct processes - there is no GIL contention among them.  If, in addition, you're running multiple threads in any of the processes, then it *might* be an issue.  In the meantime, perhaps you can learn something from [the resource module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html). `getrusage()` can show various stats about interesting system events.